# Placing lyrics above the staff in LilyPond

Tags: lilypond, engraving

In the following MWE, I somehow can't find a way to place the lyrics above the staff:

```
\version "2.19.84"

soprano = {
  c''4 d'' e''
}

alto = {
  g' a' b'
}

tenor = {
  c' d' e'
}

words = \lyricmode { 
  Text goes above!
}

\new Staff <<
  \new Voice = "sopranoVoice" { \voiceOne \soprano }
  \new Lyrics \with { alignAboveContext = "sopranoVoice" } \lyricsto "sopranoVoice" \words
  \new Voice { \voiceTwo \tenor }
  \new Voice { \voiceThree \alto }
>>
```

[image]

I've tried following the [relevant portion of the LilyPond documentation](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.19/Documentation/notation/techniques-specific-to-lyrics), but to no avail. Placing the `alignAboveContext` line above the soprano results in an error. Perhaps the problem is multiple voices in a single staff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to work when using `alignAboveContext` with the [staff](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.19/Documentation/notation/techniques-specific-to-lyrics.en.html):

```
\version "2.19.84"

soprano = {
  c''4 d'' e''
}

alto = {
  g' a' b'
}

tenor = {
  c' d' e'
}

words = \lyricmode { 
  Text goes above!
}

\new Staff = "staff" <<
  \new Voice = "sopranoVoice" { \voiceOne \soprano }
  \new Lyrics \with { alignAboveContext = "staff" } \lyricsto "sopranoVoice"         \words
  \new Voice { \voiceTwo \tenor }
  \new Voice { \voiceThree \alto }
>>
```

Comment: Didn't succeed in posting an image though…

Comment: Oof, that was easy. And I see that now in the documentation. Thanks!

Comment: @Richard No stupid questions, but sometimes, easy answers..